# Sublime Text 3 keyboard shortcut to jump from Find Bar to text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I would like to jump from the Find Bar back to the text being edited, while keeping the Find Bar open. Currently I do it with a mouse click. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this, or how do I create one?

Comment: Found a workaround: `Ctrl+P,Esc` will end up with cursor back in the edit area.